# Why were my comments deleted from the answer?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, deletion

My comments were deleted from this answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/11274/279

Basically I commented on the answer and wanted clarification. The answer acknowledge that but my comments and answer comments were both deleted. Can I find the reason?

Comment: i was wondering that too, i was also commenting in that answer, and my comments are deleted too. until i saw this question of yours on meta, i thought u deleted your own comments, and flagged the other comments to be deleted.  i believe moderators should leave any comments untouched.

Answer (score 2):

Comments should be used to ask for more information, and not insight debate or extended discussions, our chatrooms are open for respectful debate and discussion if you want to do so.  Yes I could have left the first two comments, but the first was only going to insight debate, as well as it was clear that was the agenda from your later comments.  For that reason, I saw it best to delete them,  and if you want to discuss then go to the chatroom.

Comment: the comments that were left in that post **looked** like a debate between me and muslim1, but actually, they were further clarification of the answer in context of the question. and any third person reader would find the comments useful

Comment: @Alummat the comments were related to the post and were not instigating a debate. Further, you made another mistake. You did not post any comment that our comments were were deleted for this and that reason. Even I posted another comment, `why my comments were deleted`. Even that comment was deleted **without notifying me** that my comments have been inappropriate and that I should discuss it on meta.

Comment: @user2724 anything that you could consider useful clarification for a third party user should be edited into the answer. On the other hand anything that even looks like a debate should be deleted. That's how the system is supposed to work.